# Why my @property decorator getter is not recognised?

Tags: python-3.x, properties

My @property is not recognized in **init** method. Other getters are plain getters that don't include DB calls and validation.

```
    @property
    def project_id(self):
        try:
            self.__conn_cursor.execute(self.project_id_query)
            response = self.__conn_cursor.fetchone()
            self.__project_id = response[0]
            return self.__project_id
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized"? Do you have an error or something?

Comment: It is unresolved reference in the Pycharm, and on the other side, properties defined with simple return ex. (self.__project_name) is recognized.

Comment: Please post the error. I don't understand what you are saying.  The linter says it is unrecognized? Does the code still run?